# Locus of a point given intrinsic differential relation between radius of curvature and $\psi $ angle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find locus of point (in the plane, polar coordinates $r,\theta$ ) if variable curvature $1/R$ is proportional to $ \sin^3\psi , \psi$ being variable angle between radius vector and tangent to the curve.

$$ R = c/ \sin ^3 \psi $$

EDIT1/2:

Tangent slope $\phi$ ccw angle convention

$$ \phi = \theta + \psi \tag1 $$
[image]

Differentiate w.r.t. arc

$$ \frac{1}{R} = \frac{\sin \psi}{r} +\psi^{'} \tag2 $$

$$ \theta ^{'}= {\sin \psi}/{r},  \quad r^{'}= \cos \psi; \tag3 $$

in differential geometric form when primed w.r.t. arc for $(r,\theta)$. Next after differentiating  (2) w.r.t arc

$$ \frac{-R^{'}}{R^2} =  \frac{ r \cos \psi \;\psi^{'}-\sin\psi \cos \psi} {r^2} +\psi^{''} \tag4 $$

to eliminate $r$ we substitute from (2)

Please help to find ODE involving $ \psi $ and its derivatives *only*.

Comment: I did not close vote but you can add what you tried.

Comment: I set up this problem. May solve by considering dot product of radius vector and normal vector in the way defined.

Comment: I dont have sufficient knowledge about this, maybe you can try $r = \frac{(1+m^2)^{3/2}}{m'_x}$ and slope of normal as $\frac{-dx}{dy}$ and slope of point of locus in question $(a,b)$ as $\arctan(b/a)$ ?

Comment: Pretty uglly this way

Comment: Added a sketch about this property as a differential equation.

Comment: Yes I understood what you mean. But that's all the knowledge I have..

Comment: @ King Tut Hope you can take it further for interesting findings.